# How to encode a linear transformation from $M_n(F) \to M_n(F)$

Tags: linear-algebra, linear-transformations

$\newcommand\nullspace{\mathscr{N}}$
$\newcommand\F{\mathbb F}$
$\renewcommand\vec{\mathbf}$

I'm taking a linear algebra course and we recently proved that any linear transformation from an $m$-dimensional vector field $V$ to an $n$-dimensional vector field $W$ can be encoded as some matrix $A \in M_{m \times n}(\F)$, where $\F$ is the scalar field of $V$ and $W$.

I was asked to find the range and nullspace of the linear transformation $L: M_2(\mathbb{R}) \to M_2(\mathbb{R})$ given by
$$\begin{equation*}
     L\begin{pmatrix}
        a & b \\
        c & d
     \end{pmatrix} = \begin{pmatrix}
        b-c & d-a \\
        c-b & a-d
     \end{pmatrix}.
\end{equation*}$$
My initial approach was to solve for $\nullspace(L)$ and $\mathscr{R}(L)$ by finding the matrix representation $A$ of $L$ and solving $A \vec{x} = \vec{0}$ for the null space and $A ^T \vec{x} = \vec{0}$ for the column space. However, I couldn't derive a matrix $A \in M_2(\mathbb{R})$ that encoded the transform. I conjectured that $M_2(\mathbb{R})$ is in fact 4-dimensional because the set
$$\begin{equation*}
\left\{\begin{pmatrix}
    1 & 0 \\
    0 & 0
\end{pmatrix}, \begin{pmatrix}
    0 & 1 \\
    0 & 0
\end{pmatrix}, \begin{pmatrix}
    0 & 0 \\
    1 & 0
\end{pmatrix}, \begin{pmatrix}
    0 & 0 \\
    0 & 1
\end{pmatrix}\right\}
\end{equation*}$$
is linearly independent and spans $M_n(\mathbb{R})$, but it's impossible to left-multiply an element of $M_n(\mathbb{R})$ by a $4 \times 4$ matrix.

How do I represent the linear transformation as a matrix?

Comment: How are you representing "$\begin{pmatrix}a & b \\ c & d\end{pmatrix}$" as "an [element of an] $m$-dimensional vector field $V$" so that the theorem you recite applies?  A 2x2 array of numbers is not a usual representation of a vector.

Comment: Thank you, I just realized my mistake. The matrices are the elements of the vector field, but their represention would be as a linear combination of the standard basis matrices that I listed above, which would take the form of a vector in $F^4$.

Comment: Bingo!  :)  :)  :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'll stick to $M_2$ for concreteness but everything I'm about to say generalizes to $M_n$. You're correct that $M_2$ is $4$-dimensional; the "standard" choice for a basis is the matrices $E_{11}, E_{12}, E_{21}, E_{22}$ which have a $1$ in the entry determined by their subscript and $0$s otherwise. When you write a matrix as a linear combination of elements of this basis you get

$$M = \left[ \begin{array}{cc} m_{11} & m_{12} \\ m_{21} & m_{22} \end{array} \right] = \sum_{1 \le i, j \le 2} m_{ij} E_{ij}.$$

In other words, you've converted the $2 \times 2$ matrix into a vector $\left[ \begin{array}{c} m_{11} \\ m_{12} \\ m_{21} \\ m_{22} \end{array} \right]$. This operation is called **[vectorization](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vectorization_(mathematics))** and denoted $\text{vec}$, although as a warning it's highly non-unique: it depends on a choice of ordered basis of matrices, and different choices (even the same basis with a different ordering) will give you different vectors. Then you multiply this vector by a $4 \times 4$ matrix, then "de-vectorize" the result back into a matrix. With respect to this basis, $L$ has the $4 \times 4$ matrix

$$\left[ \begin{array}{cccc} 0 & 1 & -1 & 0 \\
 -1 & 0 & 0 & 1 \\
 0 & -1 & 1 & 0 \\
 -1 & 0 & 0 & -1 \end{array} \right].$$

A certain kind of person will find this conceptually unsatisfying because of the need to make a highly non-unique choice, but it's worth knowing at least theoretically that linear transformations on matrices are themselves just bigger matrices and don't require any new theory to describe.

Comment: The representation of any vector depends upon your basis, so it seems like vectorization is well-defined because a matrix $A \in M_n(F)$ will have a unique representation given an ordered basis $\mathscr{B}$ of the space, the same for any element of any vector space.

Comment: @Nolan: yes, but even once you've picked a basis of $F^n$ you still have to make an *additional* choice of basis of $M_n(F)$, and it has to be in a specific order. There's no strong reason to prefer the order $E_{11}, E_{12}, E_{21}, E_{22}$ over the order $E_{11}, E_{21}, E_{12}, E_{22}$, for example; I just happen to like reading matrices by rows first. Others might pick the other convention and this is the sort of thing you'd have to watch out for you if you were e.g. using the vectorization function in some programming language.